# Is it OK to make a REST API request from within a Redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a React component named `ItemList` which loads a list of items from an API server and then renders them as a list of `Item` components.

Each `Item` has a delete button.  When the button is clicked, I want to send a request to the API server to delete the item, then re-render the `ItemList`.

One way I can think of to make that work is to move both API queries into reducers, and then dispatch actions whenever I want to a) get all items; and b) delete an item.  Upon successful completion of those API operations, the reducer will update the store and the `ItemList` will re-render.

Is that a reasonable approach, or is it a bad idea to put API calls inside of reducers?

Here's a simplified version of the the code I have so far.  It doesn't yet use Redux.  I want to make sure my approach is sound before implementing Redux, hence this Stack Overflow question.

**ItemList.js**

```
class ItemList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://api.example.com/api/v1.0/item';
    fetch(url, {
      method: "get"
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({items: response.data});
    });
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
        <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  }
}
```

**Item.js**

```
class Item extends Component {

  deleteClicked() {
    /** 
     *  Is it ok to dispatch a "delete item" action 
     *  from here and then make the actual API call 
     *  in a reducer?
     */
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <h2>{item.title}</h2>
      <a onClick={this.deleteClicked}>delete item</a>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're almost solved your task. To make you solution perfect use [Action creators](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions) to make async calls and dispatch actions on completion. Reducer should be [pure sync function](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers).

For example `ItemList` component may use such action creator to extract items

```
const ExtractItemsAction = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch ({type: ITEMS_REQUESTED});
    const url = 'https://api.example.com/api/v1.0/item';
    fetch(url, {
        method: "get"
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        dispatch({type: ITEMS_RECEIVED, items: response.data});
    });
}
```

And reducer will stay pure

```
function reducer (state = initalState, action)
{
    switch (action.type) {
        case ITEMS_REQUESTED:
            return { ...state, itemsRequested: true }
        case ITEMS_RECEIVED:
            return { ...state, itemsRequested: false, items: action.items }
        default
            return state;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) you component to Redux, and use [Redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) as middleware when creating store.

Comment: Excellent point about keeping the reducer pure.  That hadn't occurred to me.  The solution you suggest for doing the API call within the action creator should work great for me. Thanks!